# Loading and running remote applications with Linux. Not ssh

Tags: linux, networking, remote

I am wanting to load an application from a remote Linux pc and run it on the one that I am sitting at. My goal is different than just using telnet or ssh, because by doing that I would still be running the program on the remote computer. It would be useing the RAM and CPU of the remote computer.

Basically I want to run applications without them being installed on all of my computers, but without bogging down the server computer's RAM and CPU.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by setting up your server as an nfs-server and mount the nfs share on your client. The first step is creating the nfs share by installing the required packages, adding a line like "/opt *(ro)" to the file "/etc/exports" and starting the needed services. Which packages you have to install and which service you have to start depend on the flavour of Linux you're using. After this install all applications to the directory "/opt" on the server. Next you set up your client as nfs client by installing the required packages and mounting the nfs share by issuing "mount :/opt /opt" (replace  with the ip of your server). Please be aware you have to add a line to "/etc/fstab" to have the nfs share be mounted on system startup of your client...

Some application may work this way, some will not. Generally those will work which can be installed completly to one directory and not placing file to other (system) directories like "/etc".

Comment: I think that I will try using samba.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something called X11 forwarding. ssh to your server with `ssh -Y user@servername` and then when you get a prompt type the name of your app `/usr/bin/firefox` for example. I'm assuming the client is Linux as well.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this still runs the program on the server computer and simply displays the graphical result on the client screen. This isn't what I want.

Comment: Okay, I upvoted happenpappen's answer